# Роль ViewModel в паттерне MVVM

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Добрый день, подскажите, пожалуйста, какова роль ViewModel-класса в паттерне MVVM (разрабатывается модульное Silverligt-приложение, функционал модулей которого со временем планируется наращивать)? 
В первую очередь интересует, чем следует ограничить ответственность этого класса? Ясно, что этот класс содержит данные, отображаемые в представлении. Но как быть с обработчиками пользовательских команд, где обрабатывать данные, поступающие из прокси, стоит ли оставить всю эту логику в данном классе, или же создать контроллер и вынести в него?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Взгляните на [patterns & practices: Prism][1].


  [1]: http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/topics/4770/prism-v4-silverlight-4

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/120090/who-should-control-navigation-in-an-mvvm-application

Answer (score 1):

[Приложения WPF с шаблоном проектирования модель-представление-модель представления](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Модель представления (ViewModel) содержит ту логику, которую по каким-либо причинам нежелательно или невозможно вынести в Модель (Model). Обычно это 1) связываемые свойства, 2) обработчики команд. Всю абстрактную, вообще говоря, независимую от платформы (.NET, Java и т.п.) логику выносят в Модель, а ту логику, которая привязана к платформе и представлению, выносят в Модель Представления.  В пределе должны получиться XAML-файлы для Представления, cs-файлы для Модели Представления и cs-файлы для Модели, причем реально Модель может быть реализована на чем угодно: C/C++ и т.п.